# Indent 2 spaces for switch statement in php-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, switch-statement, elisp

I setup 2 spaces for php-mode (using `c-basic-offset`) but switch statement remain 4 spaces,

```
function foo($items) {
  foreach($item in $items) {
    switch($item) {
        case 1:
            return 10;
        case 2:
            return 20;
    }
  }
}
```

how to change swich statement to be 2 spaces if `c-basic-offset` is 2?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. Are you using `php-mode` or `php+-mode`? What is the value of `php-mode-coding-style`?

Comment: I use php-mode (from https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode). No matter what value that var have the indent is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the `case-label` offset:

```
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 
  (lambda () (c-set-offset 'case-label 0)))
```

For more information, look at the definition of coding styles in `php-mode.el` (looking for `c-add-style` calls).

Comment: If I set `(c-set-offset 'case-label 2)` it work for case but not the block inside.

Answer (score 1):

With help from @tungd I have code that work:

```
(c-set-offset 'case-label 2)
(c-set-offset 'statement-case-intro 2)
```